# how to set border-color of parent elementsame as the color of child element when hover over that child,

Tags: html, css, parent-child

this is structure of html

```
<div class="parent">     
    <div class="child1" style="background: red;"></div>     
    <div class="child2" style="background: blue;"></div>  
</div>
```

i want to make `border-color` of `.parent` element **red** when i `hover` over `.child1` and **blue** when i `hover` over `.child2`

using only CSS.

is it possible.

---

i am new to web, so i ask on chatGPT. it produce some garbage code that didn't work.

```
.parent:hover {
  border-color: red;
}

.child1:hover ~ .parent {
  border-color: blue;
}

.child2:hover ~ .parent {
  border-color: green;
}
```

Comment: _"i am new to web, so i ask on chatGPT."_ - you should rather not do that; that is in no way a proper way to _learn_ stuff.

Answer (score 2):

finally i got my answer.

`:has()` solved my problem.
here is the `css` code

```
.parent:has(.child1:hover){
   border-color: red;
}
.parent:has(.child2:hover){
   border-color: blue;
}
```

here is the page that i was working on.

codePen: https://codepen.io/manoj1310/pen/WNaxRqa

Comment: _":has() solved my problem."_ - hope you are aware of the browser support? In Firefox this will currently only work, if the user explicitly activates it by changing the corresponding flag in their configuration - https://caniuse.com/css-has